# Управление лентой ARGB с помощью Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Есть вентилятор с подсветкой ARGB. Внутри лента с количеством диодов 12шт. Снизу предоставил код, где 6 диодов статично светят красным, 6 - желтым. Как сделать вращение по кругу из этих двух цветов?

Фото вентилятора:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZrBO.jpg

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define LED_PIN 5
#define LED_PIN 6
#define LED_NUM 12

CRGB strip[LED_NUM];
 
void setup()
{
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 5, GRB>(strip, LED_NUM);
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 6, GRB>(strip, LED_NUM);
  FastLED.setBrightness(255);
}
 
void loop()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < LED_NUM; i++) {
    strip[0] = CRGB::Red;
    strip[1] = CRGB::Yellow;
    strip[2] = CRGB::Yellow;
    strip[3] = CRGB::Yellow;
    strip[4] = CRGB::Yellow;
    strip[5] = CRGB::Yellow;
    strip[6] = CRGB::Yellow;
    strip[7] = CRGB::Red;
    strip[8] = CRGB::Red;
    strip[9] = CRGB::Red;
    strip[10] = CRGB::Red;
    strip[11] = CRGB::Red;
    
  }
  FastLED.show();
}
```

Comment: `strip = strip[1:] + strip[:1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define LED_PIN 5
#define LED_PIN 6
#define LED_NUM 12

CRGB strip[LED_NUM];

int first_led = LED_NUM;
int last_led = LED_NUM - 6;

void setup() {
   FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 5, GRB>(strip, LED_NUM);
   FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 6, GRB>(strip, LED_NUM);
   FastLED.setBrightness(255);
   for (int i = 0; i < LED_NUM; i++) {
     strip[i] = CRGB::Red;
   }
}


void loop() {
    if (++first_led >= LED_NUM)
       first_led = 0;
    strip[first_led] = CRGB::Yellow;
    strip[last_led] = CRGB::Red;
    if (++last_led >= LED_NUM)
       last_led = 0;

    FastLED.show();
    delay(100);
}
```